# Error C000000D when giving a too short message in the BCryptEncrypt winapi

Tags: c, winapi, rsa, bcrypt

I'm trying to encrypt a simple message using a public PEM RSA key using some Winapi but I get a strange behavior from my program.

When I supply a 128+ bytes long message to two `BCryptEncrypt` API calls everything works as expected. But when I supply a message shorter than that I'm getting a C000000D (`STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER`) error code.

This is the code I use ( without all the debugging lines )

```
//1024 bits public key from https://travistidwell.com/jsencrypt/demo/
CHAR key[216] = "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCAriYPFSlSVPprEN0jcg+K+AHMNAanHsfYELEIIrMRirFkzNQ3Zk+YSf1d3qZqGSqmUk6iaawMIh55Usfavnv9DCJtRnE9uHe1F1cgMnm+dug3dzOAiiSb5aIO5JqTK6LCtR+ccubCtw4geUGEk+nN0e0nk6BxRzjRIRGd5bJWDQIDAQAB";


//Get the length of the future base64 decoded public key
DWORD dwBufferLen = 0;
CryptStringToBinaryA(key, 0, CRYPT_STRING_BASE64, NULL, &dwBufferLen, NULL, NULL);

//Allocate a new buffer and redirect the output base64 decoded key to it
LPBYTE pbBuffer = NULL;
pbBuffer = (LPBYTE)LocalAlloc(0, dwBufferLen);

CryptStringToBinaryA(key, 0, CRYPT_STRING_BASE64, pbBuffer, &dwBufferLen, NULL, NULL);

//Get the size of the public key BLOB
DWORD cbKeyBlob = 0;
CryptDecodeObjectEx(X509_ASN_ENCODING | PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING, X509_PUBLIC_KEY_INFO,     pbBuffer, dwBufferLen, 0, NULL, NULL, &cbKeyBlob);

//Allocate a new buffer and redirect the output key BLOB to it
LPBYTE pbKeyBlob = NULL;
pbKeyBlob = (LPBYTE)LocalAlloc(0, cbKeyBlob);

CryptDecodeObjectEx(X509_ASN_ENCODING | PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING, X509_PUBLIC_KEY_INFO, pbBuffer, dwBufferLen, 0, NULL, pbKeyBlob, &cbKeyBlob);

//Import that key BLOB to a BCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE
BCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE hKey = NULL;

CryptImportPublicKeyInfoEx2(X509_ASN_ENCODING, pbKeyBlob, 0, 0, &hKey);

//Get the size of the future encrypted message
char* secretMsg = "Hello this message will be sent to Alice";
ULONG secretMsgSize = strlen(secretMsg);

ULONG dwOutputSize = 0;

BCryptEncrypt(hKey, secretMsg, secretMsg Size, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, &dwOutputSize , 0);

//Create a new buffer and allocate the dwOutputSize to the Heap
ULONG encryptedBufferSize = 0
PUCHAR encryptedBuffer;
encryptedBuffer = (PUCHAR)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, dwOutputSize);

BCryptEncrypt(hKey, secretMsg, secretMsgSize, NULL, NULL, 0, encryptedBuffer, dwOutputSize, &encryptedBufferSize, 0);
```

When I supply a 128+ bytes long message to my second BCryptEncrypt winapi everything works as expected
But when I supply a message shorter than that I'm getting a C000000D
(`STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER`) error code.

NB : I get an error on the second `BCryptEncrypt` function

NB 2 : After theses lines code there is a cleanup function of course

Comment: OT: `LPBYTE pbBuffer = NULL; LocalFree(pbBuffer);`? That `LocalFree` call is the same as `LocalFree(NULL)` which is a no-op. It's a useless call.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude you are right, little mistake from my side

Comment: And your recent edit made it *worse*. Now `pbBuffer` is uninitialized, with an indeterminate value. Passing it to `LocalFree` leads to *undefined behavior*. Just drop the call to `LocalFree`, it's not needed. Same with `LocalFree(pbKeyBlob)`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude is it good now ?

Comment: `BCRYPT_PAD_PKCS1` you need use as last param to `BCryptEncrypt`, also src code code be optimized too

Comment: @RbMm you are right, BCRYPT_PAD_PKCS1 made it work, do you see any other red flag on my code ?

Comment: @RoderickForest - main - the RSA keys not designed for direct encrypt (large) data. it is ok encrypt/decrypt only data which is <= then block size (say 256 bytes for 2048 bit key) for large data - you need generate some symmetric key (say AES256 key) and encrypt data with it. and encrypt symmetric key with RSA key. also your current code can be optimized - you call all api 2 times in src code - possible call it only once (in runtime will be 2 calls but in src - 1)

Comment: @RbMm My project is only text message based so RSA is perfect for this, now I'm trying to decrypt the encrypted data with private key but it's a bit hard because I can't use CryptImportPublicKeyInfoEx2, what winapi should I use ?

Comment: @RoderickForest - no, not exist *text message* exist only message **size**. if size always will be <= than rsa key size - this os ok. but if size can be more - not ok. for decrypt need private key.

Comment: @RbMm yes message will always be <= than rsa key size, what api I use for decrypt message with private key ?

Comment: @RoderickForest - `BcryptDecrypt` of course. strange question.

Comment: @RbMm yes but to import the private key, what API  ?

Comment: BCryptImportKeyPair

Comment: @RbMm thanks for everything, have a good week end my friend

Answer (score 1):

With the help of a nice member I managed to solve my issue by changing 1 parameter to the 2 BCryptEncrypt API's :

```
BCryptEncrypt(hKey, secretMsg, secretMsg Size, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, &dwOutputSize , BCRYPT_PAD_PKCS1);

BCryptEncrypt(hKey, secretMsg, secretMsgSize, NULL, NULL, 0, encryptedBuffer, dwOutputSize, &encryptedBufferSize, BCRYPT_PAD_PKCS1);
```

Comment: Could you please flag this for highlight?